# C++ get each charter of string in UTF-8, CP1251, KOI8-R, upper and lower case

Tags: c++, c, string, utf-8

I have a file consisting of UTF-8 strings. I need to read this file by strings. After that I want to get each character of this string as C string in lower case and upper case in defferent character sets(CP1251, KOI8-R, UTF-8 ...). Something like this:

`char *c_uper-UTF8;`
    `char *c_lower_UTF-8;`
    `char c_uper_CP1251;`
    `char c_lower_CP1251;`
    `etc`
    `getNChar(char* string /*string from file*/, /*pointers to each of this variables*/)`

What libary can i use for this task if it is necessary for me to run this programme both in Linux and Windows? May be i need to search a solution in Boost libraries or i cat use iconv lib, but there are no functions to get upper and lower case.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: May I ask why you need them as c-strings? It feels like you're asking for trouble, by storing UTF-8 strings as `char*`.

Comment: I don't want to sort these strings. I am creating some machine learning program for text analysing and i nead byte representation of these strings in different char sets and each character may be in upper or lower case. so don't stuff your head. i just want to get each character of string like byte array(in differernt car sets and upper and lowwer case).